# Create new keybinding in Spacemacs for timestamp with time

Tags: emacs, spacemacs

I would like to add a new keybinding in Spacemacs for orgmode to insert timestamp with time

It would be something like:

```
(spacemacs/set-leader-keys "mdh" 'insert-timestamp-with-time)
```

m => go to major mode
d => dates

h => new key to define the insert function

Given the [documentation](https://orgmode.org/manual/Creating-Timestamps.html) in "usual emacs" it is done with : `C-u C-u C-.` => calls `org-time-stamp` with double prefix.

`insert-timestamp-with-time` does not exist. I do not know how to map a call to `org-time-stamp` (which exists) with a double prefix.

Comment: You can `(defun insert-timestamp-with-time () (org-time-stamp nil))` though I don't have access to org-mode documentation here so I don't know if `nil` is correct or what to put there.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to get what i want with :

```
  (defun insert-inactive-timestamp-with-hour ()
  "Insert an inactive timestamp."
  (interactive)
  (insert (format-time-string "[%Y-%m-%d %a %H:%M:%S]" nil t))
  )


  (with-eval-after-load 'org
    (spacemacs/set-leader-keys-for-major-mode 'org-mode "dh" 'insert-inactive-timestamp-with-hour))
```